# How to Loop Data and Validate in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a dynamic input field where user can add multiple category at once. Data sent at backend is like

`['ELECTRONIC','TOYS','GAMES']`

Now I want to check for each element of the array ,if they are already present on mongodb . If its present i want to store it in `errors` object as

`errors={ 0: 'Duplicate Data found'}`

I am attaching my code for validation which is not working please help . .

```js
const Category = require('../../models/Category');


const fieldCheck = (req, res, next) => {
    const data = req.body;
    const errors = [];
    for( i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
    Category.findOne({ category_name : data[i]})
    .then(user => {
        if(user){
            // # If a reqistered User ID is found ,then move ahead
            errors[i] = 'Duplicate Entry Found';
            errors.push(errors[i]);
        } 
    }).catch(err =>{
        return res.json(err);
        }
    )
    }
    console.log(errors);
};

module.exports = fieldCheck;
```

My Category Schema is ....

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const categorySchema = new Schema ({
    category_name:{
        type:String,
        unique:true,
        isRequired:true,
        
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now()
    }
});



module.exports = mongoose.model('Category',categorySchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call an asynchronous method (`findOne`) inside a synchronous loop (`for`). As you experience, this is like oil and water.

An easy fix is to make your method asynchronous and use the `await` keyword, example:

```
const fieldCheck = async (req, res, next) => {
    const data = req.body;
    const errors = [];
    try {
        for( i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
            let user = await Category.findOne({ category_name : data[i]});
            if (user) {
                // # If a reqistered User ID is found ,then move ahead
                errors[i] = 'Duplicate Entry Found';
                errors.push(errors[i]);
            }
        }
        // I assume you wanted to respond to res.json here?
        console.log(errors);
    } catch (err) {
        return res.json(err);
    }
};

module.exports = fieldCheck;
```

Comment: Good answer +1. Just wanted to point out another approach that removes the need to make several calls to the server with `Category.findOne(...) ` in a loop, it uses the `$in` operator with just a single call and maps the result to the errors array i.e. ``let users = await Category.find({ 'category_name':  { '$in': req.body } }).exec(); errors = users.map(u => `Duplicate entry found - ${u.name}`)``